# Solving the continuity equation $u_t + \nabla \cdot (uv) = 0$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

Consider the continuity equation $u_t + \nabla \cdot (u v) = 0$ where $u : \mathbb{R}^3 \times (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R},$ with smooth $v(x) : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ and initial data $u_0.$

> Suppose $-1 < \nabla \cdot v$ and $$u_0(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & -1 \leq |x| \leq 1 \\ 0 & \text{else} \end{cases}.$$
>   Show that $\Omega := \{x : u(x,1) > 0\}$ has volume greater than $\frac{4}{3}.$

---

Any ideas on how one might go about showing this, any suggestions?  I've tried to solve it, but I'm stumped on how the given assumption on the divergence of $v$ would help even if I did solve it.  Thanks!

Comment: Isn't $u_0$ also a function on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Good catch, thanks

Comment: So $u: \Bbb R^n \times (0, \infty) \to \Bbb R$, right?

Answer (score 1):

To start we could look at the characteristic equations, where I will let $u_t := q,$ $u := z,$ $\nabla u = p,$ and $x = (x,y,z)$ (excluding the time variable).
\begin{align}
\frac{dz}{dt} &= q + v \cdot p = -z(\nabla \cdot v)\\
\frac{dx}{dt} &= v.\\
\end{align}
We immediately get
\begin{align}
x - vt &= x_0\\
u(x,t) &= z(x_0(x,t),0) e^{-(\nabla \cdot v) t}\\
&= z(x - vt,0) e^{-(\nabla \cdot v) t}\\
&= \begin{cases} e^{-(\nabla \cdot v) t}  & -1 \leq |x - vt| \leq 1\\
0 & \text{else} \end{cases}
\end{align}

We have that $u(x,1) = \chi_{[-1,1]}(|x-v(x)|) e^{-(\nabla \cdot v(x))},$ but from here I am not sure where to go since the power of the exponential is a number smaller than 1.

Comment: I have a question:  how can you solve $dx/dt = v$ to get $x - vt = x_0$ when $v$ is a non-constant vector field?

Comment: $v$ is a constant with respect to time (it maps $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$), which you are integrating the equation $\frac{dx}{dt}$ with respect to time.